# Fixing a row and column excel style in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, excel

Is there a way to fix a column or row so when the user scrolls down or right, the first is always shown?

I'd need to replicate this excel feature in asp.net and am using a ListView control.

Is it at least doable in html? I'm open to any suggestion to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/09/freezing_gridview_column_heade_1.html) explains how to do it using a Gridview and CSS only, but it does not appear to be compatible with Firefox.

[This article](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/09/freezing_gridview_column_heade.html) explains how to do it with a GridView, a Control Adapter, and CSS.

[This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/07/31/freeze-asp-net-gridview-headers-by-creating-client-side-extenders.aspx) explains how to do it by extending the GridView control.  This one, to my eye, seems the best, simplest approach.

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) also has a GridView in their control toolkit that is capable of this. They have a demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/scrolling/defaultcs.aspx).